# Symfony Doctrine Undefined Index

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm trying yo make a Doctrine Query by using join queries.
I have done the following thing :

```
    public function getCategoriesFromCategorieParentAndConstructeur(): ?Array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->leftJoin('c.categorie_parent_id', 'cp' )
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

But when I try to display the result the following error appears :

> Notice: Undefined index: categories

I have no idea why can you tell me more ?

Here are my 2 Entity
:
Categorie Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategorieRepository")
 */
class Categorie
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $categorie_intitule;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\CategorieParent", inversedBy="categorie_id")
     */
    private $categorie_parent_id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="categories")
     */
    private $created_by;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Produit", mappedBy="categorie_id", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $produits;
```

CategorieParent Entity

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Categorie", mappedBy="categorie_parent_id", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $categorie_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categorie_id = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCategorieIntitule(): ?string
    {
        return $this->categorie_intitule;
    }

    public function setCategorieIntitule(string $categorie_intitule): self
    {
        $this->categorie_intitule = $categorie_intitule;

        return $this;
    }
```

Tahnk you

Comment: `$created_by` points to the User entity and is inversed by `categories`. So your User does not have that property. Also if you are using it check the profiler, you might have invalid entities.

Comment: Can you include `App\Entity\User` entity mappings

Answer (score -2):

You could follow what this Notice tells you and define your variable `$categories` in your User entity, which will probably be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=App\Entity\Categorie, mappedBy="created_by")
 */
private $categories;
```

and this should be the best option, since it will give you a correct mapping between DB and Entities.

Otherwise you can just [disable notice reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867082/4820276):

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); 
?>
```

Comment: Disable error reporting? Seriously?  Plus your disabling approach will not work for this question.  Consider updating your 'answer'.  Might even consider posting a working answer instead of a guess.

Comment: @Cerad My First solution should solve the problem, as Martin M. wrote. But since it's a Notice, things should work disabling error(or just notice) reporting without having side effects. Of course a correct entity mapping is the right way to go.

Comment: Still wrong on both counts.  Try implementing your solution to see why it won't work.  Normally not a down voter but will make an exception in this case.

Comment: @Cerad Disable error reporting is just a workaround, not a complete solution, as i wrote. Adding $categories field with mappedBy="created_by" should solve it in the best way. If that's not the case i deserve that downvote and i'll follow this question to understand where i am wrong.

Comment: Until OP responds and shares what exactly is needed, we won't know if this is the correct approach. But according to the [doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) simply adding the property in the User entity is not enough. A reference column needs to be set for `$created_by` as it is missing in the original post. Oh yeah, and the ArrayCollection part too is missing.

Comment: Hi all @MartinM.you're solution in commentaries solved my problem, unfortunately I can't mark it as solved.